# in gcc linker, arrays with a specific section attribute placed in the section in reverse order of appearance in the source code

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, ld

I tried to do a simple test and came across with this problem.
I have a linker script that says below

```
. = 0x70000000;
.compnn_stcweights : {
    *(.compnn_weights)
}
```

this means any data with section attribute ".compnn_weights" should be placed in virtual address 0x70000000.  and I have a header file

```
unsigned short __attribute__ ((__section__(".compnn_stcweights"))) stcWeight0[] = {
...
};
unsigned short __attribute__ ((__section__(".compnn_stcweights"))) stcWeight1[] = {
...
};
...
unsigned short __attribute__ ((__section__(".compnn_stcweights"))) stcWeight74[] = {
...
};
```

but after compiling, when I open the .map file, I see below.

```
 .compnn_stcweights
                0x70000000  0x764f23a ./obj/aiwareAbc.o
                0x70000000                stcWeight74
                0x7001fffe                stcWeight73
                0x700b09fe                stcWeight72
                   ...
                0x7763b3fa                stcWeight3
                0x7764467a                stcWeight2
                0x776457ba                stcWeight1
                0x7764ea3a                stcWeight0
```

Why are the stcWeightsX arrays placed int section in reverse order? I want stcWeight0 to appear first in the section. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Section names with a dot are reserved for the system. Prefer section names without a leading dot in your code. Does `*(SORT(.compnn_weights))` work?

Comment: thanks for the advice and suggestion. I tried that SORT but it didn't work (if I had given separate section name to each array, that could work I guess).